# How can I use websocket in shared IP, Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID?

Tags: php, websocket

I am currently working in websocket with php project. I want to run and use the web socket `wss`. But when I tried it as `wss://ip:8080` (shared ip of server) it says the error in console of chrome as `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. But the `ws` is working fine. In the coding I had used the certificate of cloudflare.

```
public function handle()
    {
        $loop   = Factory::create();
        $webSock = new SecureServer(
            new Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop),
            $loop,
            array(
                'local_cert'        => '/home/virtfs/saman/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.crt/server.crt', // path to your cert
                'local_pk'          => '/home/virtfs/saman/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.key/server.key', // path to your server private key
                'allow_self_signed' => FALSE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false in production)
                'verify_peer' => FALSE
            )
        );
        // Ratchet magic
        $webServer = new IoServer(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new WebSocketController()
                )
            ),
            $webSock
        );
        $loop->run();
    }
```

Then I [heard](https://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21187#p89422) that for wss we should use domain name. Then I [checked](https://transparencyreport.google.com/https/certificates) the domain name for its certificate validity, it says it valid up to 2020.
[image]. But how can I use the virtual host directive for this request, please.

`wss://139.50.60.85:8080` to `https://wss.sample.com`

**Is this correct?** 
**Because it is shared IP, will this affect other sites?**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  # Common SSL Config
  ServerName wss.sample.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/virtfs/saman/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.crt/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/virtfs/saman/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.crt/server.key"
  DocumentRoot "/home/saman/www/api"
  <Directory  "/home/saman/www/api">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
  # Websocket proxy
  # wss redirects to working ws protocol
  ProxyPass /wss 139.50.60.85:8080 retry=0 keepalive=On 
  ProxyPassReverse /wss 139.50.60.85:8080 retry=0 
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update:**

I checked the certificate file it is valid

[image]

Comment: why would you use port 8080 for TLS-based connection? please change to HTTPS equivalent ports that Cloudflare supports: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-

Comment: I found that port `8080` is for non encrypted connection.

Comment: exactly! use 8443 for example

Comment: Then, will it works?

Comment: have you tried or not?

Comment: mm. Not working

Comment: I checked over https://www.websocket.org/echo.html then ,WebSocket connection to 'wss://139.50.60.85:8443/?encoding=text' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: I checked the certificate which is valid

Comment: Is your **origin** certificate valid? Not to be confused with Cloudflare **edge** certificate, they are different thing.

Comment: Actually, where is the origin certificate be?

Comment: at your server of course. have you created a certificate in the first place? did you use certbot/let's encrypt, self-signed or Cloudlare origin CA cert? is the cert still valid?

Comment: What's about my updated image? Is it correct? And this is not local PC, it is server with CentOS 7

Comment: that image output comes from where? you input Cloudflare's IP or your server's public IP? btw OS type doesn't matter here, but is the server even up? can't see any port open on `139.50.60.85`

Comment: I got it from https://ssldecoder.org the IP is server IP(shared IP), and also the port is enabled in firewall

Comment: `In the coding I had used the certificate of cloudflare.` By this, I assume you mean you're using Cloudflare origin CA certificate in your origin? If this is the case, I'm afraid its purpose is only to encrypt connection between Cloudflare edge and your origin and can't be used for anything else. You can't use the certificate to connect directly to your origin without going through an orange clouded DNS record in Cloudflare.

Comment: So, how can I use, what is your suggestion?

Comment: If you want to use [Cloudflare Origin CA certificate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507-Managing-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-certificates) on your server, make sure the connection is proxied through your domain/subdomain managed in Cloudflare. Otherwise, if you want to continue using websockets by referencing server's IP address, install other free certificates like Let's Encrypt on your server.

Comment: Oh! no, If I use the websocket by IP, it is mixed type because the URL is https. So I want to redirect it to a domain name. Now I want to USE the websocket of `wss://139.50.60.85:8080` to `https://wss.sample.com`. How do I do this?

Comment: Still using port 8080 lol. Never listens to people's advice. Good luck to you man! I'm out

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Now I am using port `8443`. But I mentioned the port `8000` here for the reference. Because my question is fall on that port.